# Можно ли как нибудь убрать (спрятать) курсор в RichTextBoxe'е?

Tags: c#, winforms, хук

Здравствуйте!
Можно ли как нибудь убрать (спрятать) курсор в RichTextBoxe'е?

Comment: Хм. Установить [`ReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx) пробовали?

Comment: Да пробовал! Он так же остаеться!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    HideCaret(TextBox.Handle);
}

private void TextBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HideCaret(TextBox.Handle);
}
```

Впрочем, если вам нужна всего лишь надпись в рамке, то есть способы и попроще

Comment: @DreamChild Нет мне надо что бы можно было выделять текст!

Comment: а где у вас это в вопросе написано? или об этом нужно было догадаться?

Comment: Спасибо все работает!!!!!

Comment: А режим только чтение не устраивает?

Comment: Нет не подходит